# Solving $P( Y < 0.5 | X > 0.5)$

Tags: probability

On the following page

[$P(Y<.5 | X >.5), P(Y>2X), P(.5<X+Y<1.5)$ with Joint probability density function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370822/py-5-x-5-py2x-p-5xy1-5-with-joint-probability-density-functio)

it gives the following problem...

"Let X and Y have the joint probability density function

$f(x,y)=\frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2), 0<x<1,0<y<1$

a.) Find $P(Y<.5|X>.5)$. My answer is $\frac{5}{11}$."

As I am trying to solve a similar problem, I trying to understand how they arrived at $\frac{5}{11}$.

To solve this problem I thought you would first find the conditional density of Y. Then plug in x and the solve the integral with y's condition. However, I do not come up with the same answer. Could someone explain the process?

Answer (score 3):

I get a different result:

$$P(Y<\frac{1}{2}|X>\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{P((Y<\frac{1}{2}) \cap (X>\frac{1}{2}))}{P(X>\frac{1}{2})} $$ 
$$= \frac{\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy}{ \frac{3}{2}\int_0^1\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy } $$
 $$=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{11}{16}} = \frac{4}{11}$$